# How can I navigate to PHP page? I have tried using hyper link but that is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have dropdown menu in side navbar. And each menu have sub-menu.

My directories are

```
RBS
 |
 +-- All php files are here
 |--one.php
 |--two.php
 |    
 +-- css
 |  |  
 |  +-- all css files here
 |    
 +-- js
 |  |  
 |  +-- Javascript here
 |  
 |    
 +-- includes
 |  |  
 +  |-- menu.php //navbar file is here
```

I want to give link of all php files in menu.php. I know there are many solutions out there but my grip is not good on javascript.

My menu PHP script is given below

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Generalmanager</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/menu.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/hover.css">
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    </head>

    <body onclick="closeNav()">

    <div id="sidebar" class="sidenav" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

        <a class="dropdown-btn hvr-icon-hang">Raw Material Inventory
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down hvr-icon"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-container">
            <a  href=../one.php">Page one</a>
            <a href="../two.php">Page two</a>
            <a  href="#">C</a>
            <a  href="#">D</a>
        </div>
        <hr>

        <a class="dropdown-btn hvr-icon-hang">Supplier
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down hvr-icon"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-container">
            <a href="#">A</a>
            <a  href="#">B</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <span class="menu" onclick="openNav(event)">&#9776; Menu</span>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. _"I have tried using hyper link but that is not working"_ - not working means what? Please show what you have tried! A simple `<a  href="../phpfile.php">A</a>` should do. (if you're at `menu.php` currently)

Comment: Yes, I have tried that just like you are saying. That is the problem it is not working. I'm looking for other way around.

Comment: What does "not working" look like? Do you get an JS errors in your console?

Comment: Is `menu.php` included in another file? Or in other words: what does the url in the address-bar look like? If you don't tell us what "not working" means we cannot help.

Comment: @halfer When i host my page one.php like in address bar "localhosthttp://localhost:8080/RBS/one.php", this page is working. Now within the one.php when i click on two.php it does not navigate to two.php. The problem is with the navigation(from one.php to two.php) not with the menu.php file and i'm not getting any kind of error except for css error in JS console which are "failed to load resource" as this is not the main issue. My JS only performing two functions one is opening an closing the side nav-bar and second is opening the drop-down menu with sub-menu.

Comment: Would you provide a screenshot of what happens after you click on "two.php"? Does the URL change to `http://localhost:8080/RBS/two.php`? Note also that `localhosthttp://localhost:8080/RBS/one.php` is not a valid URL.

Comment: Finally, perhaps you can provide a screenshot of your browser's Network tab, in its Developer Tools system (all the major desktop browsers have this).

Comment: I’m really Sorry my bad, I’m getting error when i click on two.php from one.php file and yes the URL change to “localhost:8080/two.php” instead of localhost:8080/RBS/two.php”. two.php file is in RBS folder but server can't find it.
Error is “Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out by removing the two dots in hyperlink in menu.php file. It is working perfectly now by using the hyperlink.

Updated answer: I'm sure for most of you sometimes hyperlink doesn't work. I have found another solution which is more reliable. You just need to pass the localhost address in hyperlink like this "http://localhost:8080/Project/abc/yourfile.php".